# Is it alright to have a sentence with a parenthetical remark that has an "i.e." and an "etc."?

Tags: parentheses

An example would be "The first field is the number (i.e. A001, A013, etc.) in accordance with..."
The actual details of the sentence do not matter, it is the parentheses that is being referenced in my question.

Comment: One of the uses of brackets is re-formulating or rephrasing for clarification; that would be obvious here, so the _ie_ or _i.e._ is unnecessary. The _etc_ is necessary and clear, though an ellipsis would probably be more normal if there are no other dot-usages.

Comment: No, that's fine, because *i.e.* and *etc.* do not overlap. However, make sure you don't confuse *i.e.* with *e.g.*, as in your example (sorry, I have to say it), because *e.g.* and *etc.* do overlap. In your example, I think you use *i.e.* where you mean *e.g.*, in which case it is redundant. As it stands, your *i.e.* is simply out of place in that example.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that it's "etc.". With exactly one period. Not zero, not three. I have edited your question accordingly.

Comment: ... according to Reg's favourite style guide. But not mine.

Comment: The point to the parenthesis is to imply "i.e." without actually having to write it. I always delete it unless the parenthetical remark is a clarifying & simplifying paraphrase of something difficult to understand but necessary because it's the standard jargon.

Answer (score 1):

No.

> *"The first field is the number (i.e. A001, A013, etc.) in accordance with..."

As you are aware, parentheses and "i.e.," serve the same purpose in this context. As such it would be incorrect to use both together.

> "The first field is the number, i.e., A001, A013, etc., in accordance with..."
>   or
>   "The first field is the number (A001, A013, etc.) in accordance with..."